# как скрыть блок для мобильных устройств и планшетов

Tags: css

Проблема в следующем: есть блок, который не нужно отображать на телефонах, планшетах. Как это сделать с помощью CSS??
Я понимаю, что вопрос может быть простейшим, но...
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: hidden-xs добавь класс, если бутстрап юзаешь =)

Comment: @korolariya, К сожалению ваш вариант не сработал(ну или у меня руки кривые =))
Но, все равно, большое спасибо

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-image-replacement

Comment: Все бы хорошо, но стоит включить кэш, всем вашим кодам грош цена. По крайней мере в joomla. Включи системный кэш и удивись.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

есть 2 метода

1. через css

пример

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #chto_ne_pozavivat {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

2. через js

пример

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var mobile = (/iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));  
    if (mobile) { 
        alert("Мобильное устройство!!");
        $('.navWrap').css('display', 'none'); // или можно $('.navWrap').hide();
    } 
    else 
    { 
       alert("НЕ мобильное устройство!"); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Зачем одновременно visiblity и display?

Comment: <div id="audioplayer287" style="width:149px;height:53px;" ></div>
а как-то в сам блок это все запихнуть можно???
P.s. прошу извинить за глупые вопросы)

Comment: @Qwertiy кому что нужно выберет. не обязательно что бы оба были.

Comment: @DaVinchi вопрос не понял. Вам только для одного блока нужно? сделайте для одного блока не проблема.

Comment: @DaVinchi, нет. Медиазапросы, псевдоэлементы и псевдоклассы невозможно поместить в inline-стиль. Только отдельный css.

Comment: спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. все просто замечательно)

Answer (score 0):

Используй media-запрос на ширину экрана.

Не используй вариант `handheld` - он устарел и на большинстве устройств не сработает.

Answer (score 0):

```
.fixed1 { display: inline; }
/* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px){ .fixed1 { display: none; }}
```

Добавил в css